# mysql: drop and recreate functions with new collation in bulk

Tags: mysql, function, collation

I have a situation where I have a number of stored functions across database tables which have the wrong collation (and appear to be triggering illegal mix of collation errors). From what I've read, you cannot alter the collation for functions "in place" -- you must drop and recreate them.

I'm looking for a way to drop and recreate with the new collation in bulk. That means I need to be able to "read" existing function definitions directly from the DB, alter the collation, and recreate it. While I know the constituent parts of the process, and could do it on a function-by-function basis, I'm having difficulty figuring out an effective way to do this in bulk -- across the entire DB.

Answer (score 2):

The following script will generate a script for you to recreate all your functions in your database as they are right now, similar to `SHOW CREATE FUNCTION`, but as a real resultset, and for all functions at the same time.

```sql
select sql_stmt 
from (
  select p.db, p.name, p.type, 1 as intord, p.character_set_client,
    concat('drop ',p.type, ' if exists ', p.db,'.`', p.name,'`;') as sql_stmt
  from mysql.proc p
  union all
  select p.db, p.name, p.type, 2 as intord, p.character_set_client,
    'delimiter $$' as sql_stmt
  from mysql.proc p
  union all
  select p.db, p.name, p.type, 3 as intord, p.character_set_client,
    concat('CREATE DEFINER=`',replace(p.definer,'@','`@`'),'` ',
      p.type, 
      ' ',p.db,'.`',p.name,
      '`(',convert(p.param_list USING utf8),') ',
      case 
        when length(p.returns) > 1 
        then concat(' RETURNS ', convert(p.returns USING utf8))
        else '' 
      end, ' \n',
      case 
        when p.is_deterministic = 'YES' then '\tDETERMINISTIC\n' 
        else '' 
      end,
      case 
        when p.language = 'SQL' THEN ''
        else concat('\tLANGUAGE ',p.language, '\n')
      end,
      case 
        when p.sql_data_access = 'CONTAINS_SQL' THEN ''
        when p.sql_data_access = 'NO_SQL' THEN '\tNO SQL\n'
        when p.sql_data_access = 'READS_SQL_DATA' THEN '\tREADS SQL DATA\n'
        when p.sql_data_access = 'MODIFIES_SQL_DATA' THEN '\tMODIFIES SQL DATA\n'
        else concat('\t',replace(p.sql_data_access,'_', ' '), '\n')
      end,
      case when p.security_type <> 'DEFINER' 
        then concat('\tSQL SECURITY ', p.security_type, '\n')
        else '' 
      end,
      case when p.comment <> '' 
        then concat('\tCOMMENT ''', 
          replace(replace(p.comment,'''',''''''),'\n','\\n')
          ,'''')
        else '' 
      end, '\n',
      convert(p.body USING utf8),
      '$$'
    ) as sql_stmt
  from mysql.proc p
  union all
  select p.db, p.name, p.type, 4 as intord, p.character_set_client,
    'delimiter ;' as sql_stmt
  from mysql.proc p

) sql_stmts
where db = <yourdbname>
and type = 'function'
and character_set_client = 'utf8'
order by db, name, type, intord;
```

The result will be in the form

```sql
drop function if exists a;
delimiter $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`127.0.0.1` FUNCTION yourdb.`a`(...
delimiter ;
drop function if exists b;
delimiter $$
...
```

Since you seem to require the command line client from bash, you can execute the script e.g. with

```sql
mysql -u root -p -N -r < thisscript.sql > recreatefunctions.sql
```

The parameters `-N` and `-r` are there to prevent the header to appear in the result and to prevent the translation of `\n` to the `'\n'`, because we want to treat the result directly as an executable script.

If you execute it e.g. in the workbench, just copy the result (`Copy rows (unquoted)`) into a new window.

You can then edit the generated script to fit your needs, by hand in an editor or automatically by a script, e.g. replace all `charset latin1` by `charset utf8`, or whatever you require.

You might also do this in the script above, it might be easier to do. You didn't elabore what has to be adjusted, but if you e.g. want to change the charset of the return parameter from `latin1` to `utf8`, you can modify the script and replace

```sql
then concat(' RETURNS ', convert(p.returns USING utf8))
```

by

```sql
then concat(' RETURNS ', replace(convert(p.returns USING utf8),'latin1', 'utf8'))
```

To finally update your functions after you edited the file, you can use

```sql
mysql -u root -p < recreatefunctions.sql
```

The script assumes that the code (the blob-fields in the `mysql.proc` table, not the charset you want to change) is saved as `utf8`. This is usually the case, but as a precaution, it only reads (and replaces) functions that where saved as `utf8`, although it should work in other cases too. You should check this in the table `mysql.proc`, column `character_set_client`. You can then replace `convert(p.param_list USING utf8))`,`convert(p.returns USING utf8))` and `convert(p.body USING utf8)` by the correct encoding, or, if you have several encodings, use a `case`-statement.

By the way, before you try it, it is not possible to do this completely inside mysql (dynamic sql in a stored procedure), because `create function` is not allowed in a dynamic sql statement.

And by the way, before you try it, make a backup!

Comment: Yes, getting the function via show create function is as far as I got. I'm scripting in bash, and there's no easy way to extract the create function "column" from the query results. That seems to be where the biggest difficulty is.

Comment: @lcdservices I wrote a version that doesn't require `show create function`. It will create the required code to recreate all of your functions, that you can then modify to your needs (or let already the script to the modifications, depending on your requirements - you didn't explain what exactly you need to change).

Comment: Wow -- that's a huge help. thanks! I'm going to run through some tests right now.